# Password validation in Java using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to check that if a password contains:

- [1,6] uppercase/lowercase characters
- [1,10] digits
- [0,1] special characters

I tried multiple approach, but without success. I don't know if I can do this verify with regex. The most accurate pattern is : `^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){1,6})(?=(.*[0-9]){1,10})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()\-__+.]){0,1})`

But it don't work good when I have more than 6 char, 10 digits or 1 special character.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not use a single regex pattern, but would instead use multiple checks.  For example:

```java
String password = "ABC123@";
int numChars = password.replaceAll("(?i)[^A-Z]+", "").length();
int numDigits = password.replaceAll("\\D+", "").length();
int numSpecial = password.replaceAll("[^!@#$%^&*()_+.-]", "").length();

if (numChars >=1 && numChars <= 6 && numDigits >= 1 && numDigits <= 10 &&
    numSpecial <= 1) {
    System.out.println("password is valid");
}
else {
    System.out.println("password is invalid");
}
```

Comment: And a even more real world solution would be: to rather use "conditions" into a list, and iterate that one by one. So it becomes much easier to change this or that condition later on, or add more.

Comment: @GhostCat I guess I should have mentioned that regex is not the best tool for counting characters, leading me to the version above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, which is the best way for validate password in my case (I am not restricted to using just regexp)?

Comment: I don't know of a "nice" way to validate your password using a one shot single regex.  The above is the best I could conjure up on the time scale of a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was wondering if there is a better option without using regex.